# Category of Presheaves on a small category $C$ is locally cartesian closed

Tags: category-theory

I'm trying to fill in the details of the proof and need the following result: $Set^{C^{op}}/P\simeq Set^{D^{op}}$, where $D$ is the category of elements of $P$. The objects are pairs $(x,C)$ with $C ∈ C $and we may take (by Yoneda) $x ∈PC$ to be $x : yC → P$ and then the arrows are just morphisms $\vartheta :x\rightarrow x'$ in the slice category $yC/P$. ($C$ ranges over $C$).

We need functors $F$ and $G$ s.t $GF\cong 1_{Set^{C^{op}}/P}$ and $FG\cong 1_{Set^{D^{op}}}$ One way is fairly obvious:

$F: Set^{C^{op}}/P \rightarrow Set^{D^{op}}$ defined by $F(q)(C, x) = Hom_{Set^{C^{op}}/P}(x, q)$

But what should the functor $G:Set^{D^{op}}\rightarrow Set^{C^{op}}/P$ be?

edit: I remembered a similar construction when proving that $Set^{I}\simeq Set/I$ so I'm just mimicking it:

I let $G$ be defined as follows: if $h∈Set^{D^{op}}$, then take $r∈ Set^{C^{op}}$ to be $r(C)=\coprod _{x\in PC}h(C,x)$, where we identify  $x ∈PC$ with $x : yC → P$. We then just project this to $PC$ and so get an object in $Set^{C^{op}}/P$, namely $\pi :r\rightarrow p$.

But now I have a question. In the proof I was following, the category of elements of $P$ was taken to be as described above. But wouldn't it be easier to just use the normal definition? Because then, if $q:Y\rightarrow P$, you can just take $F: Set^{C^{op}}/P \rightarrow Set^{D^{op}}$ to be $F(q)(C, x)=q_{c}^{-1}(x))$ This seems easier to understand.

Is this correct?

Comment: Have you heard of adjunctions between categories?

Comment: Are you sure you have everything straight? So many $C$'s! And the two appearances of $q$ have quite different types. Your problem simply might be that you have confusing notation or actually actually confused something about the particulars of the problem.

Comment: The adjoint of an equivalence functor is the other half of the equivalence.

Comment: @Hurkyl: $q$ is an object in the slice $Set^{C^{op}}/P$ and so is a morphism: $Q\rightarrow P$. How do I know that $F$ has an adjoint? Even if it did, that would not ensure equivalence. We'd need $F$ to be fully faithful I think.

Comment: If you truly believe $F$ to be one half of an equivalence, then it *is* going to be fully faithful and have an adjoint. So if you boldly charge ahead and try to write down what its adjoint would be, that would give you the $G$ you're looking for.

Comment: @ Sanath: Yes. Actually, I had observed that $F$ is related to a precomposition, namely $\pi^{*}$ because $\pi^{*}(yq)(x,C)=yq(π(x,C))=yq(x)$ and so $\pi^{*}$ has adjoint $\pi_{!}$, I do not see how to relate this back to $F$ however.

Comment: It seems this proof is done, for instance, in Awodey 2nd. ed. (Lemma 9.23 and Corollary 9.24). Link on Google Books:
https://books.google.de/books?id=UCgUDAAAQBAJ&lpg=PA237&ots=63K2eDuUVo&dq=presheaves%20locally%20cartesian%20closed&pg=PA237#v=onepage&q=presheaves%20locally%20cartesian%20closed&f=false

Comment: I cannot see how you project $ r(C) $ to $ PC $. Can you explain it please? It looks easy but I am stuck.